# Session modifiers

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using the following code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(-1,'/','myAwesomeDomain.com',true,true);
```

to secure the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

The problem is, that I can't change the cookie's name anywhere else with this:

```
session_name('_uid');
```

My question is: How to get these two methods to work with each other?
<del>Also, is there a method to refer to "When the browsing session ends" at the first parameter of the first method?</del>

PS: There IS a `session_start()` in the file :D

**EDIT:** I even accept methods tinkering with the `php.ini` file.

**EDIT v2:** The file that contains this is separate from every other and it doesn't matter how many lines of code I need to do this. Using `include_once()`.

**EDIT v3:** This is ridiculous. PHP puts a dot in front of the domain:
[image: sumPhpCookies]

Now I'm totally lost why that is. (I'm not even using the `session_name` here.)

**EDIT v4:** Code:

```
<?php
// Somehow rename PHPSESSID cookie
session_set_cookie_params(-1,'/','www.forcemagic.xyz',true,true);
session_start(); ?>
```

Comment: The browser is client side. There is (unfortunately) no way to discover whether someone closed their browser or not, as it doesn't communicate anything back to the server about it (and that's where PHP resides). Sessions simply die off after the user hasn't reloaded the page within the specified lifetime. - A javascript solution is also highly inaccurate. (believe me, I've tried)

Comment: Alright, I understand :) Then, if you can, just please help with the 1st question. Already edited :D

Comment: Not sure why you feel `session_set_cookie_params` is necessary. Surely everything can be done from a simple `setcookie`

Comment: Eh... you're right. I'm just not that experienced in this cookie/session stuff :c

Comment: Also the session name can be set in the `php.ini` so if you want to make it non standard you could do it there. But a hacker is going to work out that your cookies are cookies and what they are used for anyway, unless you encrypt the contents

Comment: That's why I'm using the HTTPS flag (isn't that enough encryption?)

Comment: Where are you calling `session_name` – before or after `session_set_cookie_params`? According to some user comments in the manual, you have to call it before. (Although these comments are several years old, it might still be true. So if you called it after, try calling it before, and see if that changes things.)

Comment: Before. Still doesn't work.

Comment: “PHP puts a dot in front of the domain […] Now I'm totally lost why that is.” – the reason for doing that, as explained in the manual, is to make the session cookie available on subdomains too. But that should only happen if you use the session with default settings; if you explicitly set the cookie parameters and specify the domain name without a leading dot, then it should not happen.

Comment: If _explicitly set the cookie parameters_ mean the `session_set_cookie_params()` thing, then I'm setting it explicitly. (If not, then how to set it explicitly??)

Comment: I phrased it that way because I was not totally sure if that screenshot showed the session cookie set with your modified settings, or a “default” one.

Comment: Can you show us the full code of the include file you said you were using?

Comment: Sure, see the edited post.

Comment: _“I even accept methods tinkering with the php.ini file”_ – yeah, give that a try as well, and see if you get different results.

Comment: `// Somehow rename PHPSESSID cookie` – well is session_name there, or is it not?

Comment: Nope. It was there, it didnt work

Comment: That PHPSESSID cookie in the screenshot is set to be valid until 2019, which seems weird. I wonder if it might have to do with that you set `-1` as first parameter for `session_set_cookie_params`? If you want the cookie to life only until the browser is closed, you should use `0`. / Also, please try and delete all cookies from your browser, and try again (just to ensure that you don’t get fooled by an old cookie hanging around, or something like that.)

Comment: `session_name('_uid')` – is `_uid` the actual value you tried to set? Or is it a numeric user id from the database or something like that? As the manual says, the name should contain of alphanumeric characters only, and is not allowed to consist of digits only, it must contain at least one letter.

Comment: that is the actual value, yes. And I have to try with 0.

Comment: Well then it doesn’t fulfill the alphanumeric characters only “requirement”, because alphanumeric means letters or digits only, not an underscore. (Requirement in quotes, because the manual only says “should” – but please try with a name that does fulfill it, just to be sure.)

Comment: Oh, okay, that works indeed. Would you mind posting that as an answer please? :) It's actually funny how it works and it WAS working, but now... well, that's PHP :D

Comment: Hah, see, I knew we’d get to the bottom of this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_name('_uid')
```

[As the manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php), the name should contain of alphanumeric characters only (letters, digits), and is not allowed to consist of digits only, it must contain at least one letter.

So that underscore was actually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `session_name` actually has to be declared *before* the `session_set_cookie_params`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
see the comment of "brandan, bildumgsroman.org"

The browser is client side. There is (unfortunately) no way to discover whether someone closed their browser or not, as it doesn't communicate anything back to the server about it (and that's where PHP resides). Sessions simply die off after the user hasn't reloaded the page within the specified lifetime. - A javascript solution is also highly inaccurate. (believe me, I've tried)

There is, however, one way to determine whether a browser has been closed or not. However, I wouldn't recommend it;

You could create a repetitive ajax call that stores a simple timestamp in the database that a user with a specific session is online. Then, you can run a cronjob on PHP checking that database for keepalive timestamps with a bigger difference between `now` and the last (2) ping(s), and then the cronjob will know that the browsing has stopped.

Comment: **From the manual** _Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called_

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're saying that it's a better practice to set it in the ini file? And how do I set it? /Sorry, I'm a beginner when it comes to session handling :P/

Comment: @ForceMagic He's saying that you need to redeclare it on every file in which you want to use it if you don't, I believe.

Comment: I'm using an include to a sessionctrl.php file :D

Comment: In that case I have no idea, but I don't want to remove my answer as @RiggsFolly 's comment is very useful

Comment: @Babydead But your answer or `brandan, bildumgsroman.org` seems to conflict with the para in the main body of the manual, I am confused now

Comment: _“Sessions simply die off after the user hasn't reloaded the page within the specified lifetime”_ – not really; they “die”, when the garbage collector cleans them up. The `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting is wrongly named, because actually, it is the opposite – it is a _minimum_ lifetime. If that time span has passed since the session was last accessed, then the GC is _allowed_ to clean it up. But since it is randomly triggered, there is no guarantee that happens immediately. […]

Comment: […] Even after that time span has passed, the session can be picked up again, if the client sends a session id to which a session file still exists. If you really want a maximum lifetime, you have to implement it yourself – f.e. by storing the last access timestamp in the session, and then on next access check the time difference, and deny access or destroy the session.

Comment: Oh, wow great knowledge/googling skills there, learned a lot with this question so far :D

Comment: @CBroe I guess I should've rephrased it into "This is a trick to find out whether the client closed down the browser".
Also, what I said still slightly counts. The lifetime gets reset every time the session gets used, which is exactly what happens when the client reloads the page. Although you are right about the GC. Can't deny that. Sessions do die off after the client closes the browser, in the sense that they won't be resetting the life timer again.